# What will be the efficient way to Replace characters from within braces?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below input

```
var input = (a-d){12-16},(M-Z){5-8},[@$%!^,12+-,23^!]
```

I need to remove the comma within the square brackets such that the final output will be

```
var output = (a-d){12-16},(M-Z){5-8},[@$%!^12+-23^!]
```

By solution

```
function test()
{
    var input = '(a-d){12-16},(M-Z){5-8},[@$%!^,12+-,23^!]'; //input string
    var splitByFirstBracket = input.split("["); //split the input by [ character    

    //merge the arrays where the second array is replaced by '' for ','
    var output = splitByFirstBracket[0] + '[' + splitByFirstBracket[1].replace(/,/g,'');    
    alert(output);
}
```

It is providing the output correctly. Is there any better way - I am open both for JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: this should be posted in [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression replacement. The replacement can be a function, which receives the part of the input that was matched by the regexp, and then it can calculate the replacement. In this case, it would use another replace call to remove the commas.

```js
var input = '(a-d){12-16},(M-Z){5-8},[@$%!^,12+-,23^!]'; //input string
var output = input.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, function(match) {
  return match.replace(/,/g, '');
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: barmar can i ask something `input.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, function(match) {` this will make `[@$%!^,12+-,23^!]` which is equal to `match`? then `match.replace(/,/g, '');` will remove the `,` please correct if am wrong i want to understand how it happened.. thank you

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. The function receives the part of the string that matches the regexp as its argument. Then whatever it returns replaces that match.